# Creating variables based on a dropdown selection from extracted XML data

Tags: php, arrays, xml, foreach, domdocument

I am extracting data from a XML document using `DOMDocument` and `foreach` loops. For one of the data points I am after, `style`, I created an associative array with the **style name** and **style ID**. I then exported the **style name** into a `<select>` dropdown. What I am trying to figure out is how to create a variable with **style ID** based on which **style name** was selected in the dropdown. Here is what I have so far:

The two **style names** are `5dr Avant Wgn Man` and `5dr Avant Wgn Auto`. These are exported to the dropdown. Their respective style Id's are `292015` and `292016`. Thus, the associative array would look something like this `5dr Avant Wgn Man => 292015` and `5dr Avant Wgn Auto => 292016`.

What I want to achieve is when `5dr Avant Wgn Man` is selected from the dropdown, `292015` is set equal to `$variable`. Thus, `echo $variable;` will display `292015`. And vice versa for the other style.

Here is my PHP:

```
<html>

<body>

<?php

 $xml = file_get_contents('data.xml');
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadXML($xml);

?>

<select>
  <option selected="selected">Choose style</option>
    <?php
      foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName('style') as $styletwo )          {
        $styleid = $styletwo->getAttribute("name");
        $styleData [$styleid]= $styletwo->getAttribute("id");;
       }
      foreach ($styleData as $k=>$v){
      ?>
       <option><?php echo $k;?> </option>
      <?php
       }
      ?>
 </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the XML document I am pulling from:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
  <VehicleDescription country="US" language="en" modelYear="2008" bestMakeName="Audi" bestModelName="S4" bestStyleName="5dr Avant Wgn" xmlns="urn:description7b.services.chrome.com">
     <responseStatus responseCode="Successful" description="Successful"/>

     <style id="292015" modelYear="2008" name="5dr Avant Wgn Man" nameWoTrim="5dr Avant Wgn Man" mfrModelCode="8ED549" fleetOnly="false" modelFleet="false" passDoors="4" altBodyType="Station Wagon" drivetrain="All Wheel Drive">
        <division id="4">Audi</division>
        <subdivision id="5020">Audi</subdivision>
        <model id="17308">S4</model>
        <basePrice unknown="false" invoice="46137.0" msrp="49610.0" destination="775.0"/>
        <bodyType primary="true" id="7">Station Wagon</bodyType>
        <marketClass id="53">Small Wagon</marketClass>
        <acode>USB80AUC085A0</acode>
     </style>
     <style id="292016" modelYear="2008" name="5dr Avant Wgn Auto" nameWoTrim="5dr Avant Wgn Auto" mfrModelCode="8ED54L" fleetOnly="false" modelFleet="false" passDoors="4" altBodyType="Station Wagon" drivetrain="All Wheel Drive">
        <division id="4">Audi</division>
        <subdivision id="5020">Audi</subdivision>
        <model id="17308">S4</model>
        <basePrice unknown="false" invoice="47162.0" msrp="50710.0" destination="775.0"/>
        <bodyType primary="true" id="7">Station Wagon</bodyType>
        <marketClass id="53">Small Wagon</marketClass>
        <acode>USB80AUC085A1</acode>
     </style>
   </VehicleDescription>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I think some kind of `if statement` with `$k` and `$v` might work but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altering your code as follows

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>
    <select name='my_select'>
       <option value='<?php echo $v;?>'>
       <?php echo $k;?> 
       </option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

Gives following HTML

```
  <select name='my_select'>
  <option selected="selected">Choose style</option>
           <option value='292015'>
       5dr Avant Wgn Man 
       </option>
             <option value='292016'>
       5dr Avant Wgn Auto 
       </option>
   </select>
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes partially. How would I then take the selected option and store it in `$variable`? So if `5dr Avant Wgn Man` were selected `292015` would be stored in `$variable`?? Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, that's right. Put <select> into form (and give it any name, for example `<select name='my_select'>`), use post method and you'll catch your option in `$variable = $_POST['my_select']`. I also updated answer

Comment: No unfortunately that doesn't work. I need `$variable` to echo right after a selection is made, and for it to echo right under the dropdown. I have tried `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: Well, if you want to work in browser in that way - ajax and js are your friends. Try this one https://jsfiddle.net/o649dj8u/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.